# What is the extent to which it is appropriate to edit a post?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, editing

Any member of this community can propose edits to any question or answer, even if originally written by someone else; the edit goes live when approved through the review queue.  For users above a certain reputation threshold, their edits are applied immediately.  This is obviously not a privilege to be used lightly, as it has lots of [potential for abuse](http://bash.org/?5775).

What is this community’s stance on the extent to which editing posts is appropriate?

Answer (score 6):

In my view, edits should:

- Preserve the meaning of the post;
- Make the post clearer:

  - For questions, make them easier to answer (up to and including a *complete rewrite*, so long as the question still invites the answers the author wanted);
  - For answers, make the existing information easier to understand;
- Preserve the voice (writing style) of the author;

in that order. (Though it's rare that you *have* to make a trade-off between these things.)

Edits should not:

- Change “colour” to “color” (or vice versa) – except in product names, where you're *sure* the product wasn't marketed both ways.
- Delete word or punctuation choices that carry meaning, without a good reason. (“It looks wrong to me” is not usually a good reason; English is an international language, and you're *all* using it wrong. Get off my lawn!)
- Add extra information to an answer.
- Add annoying Wikipedia links (though [useful ones are appreciated](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/514/278)).

Of course, these aren't hard-and-fast rules; they're just *my current* view. (I've deliberately broken all of these at one time or other, apart from the “colour”/“color” one.)

Comment: When making the post clearer, I would add that a rewrite shouldn’t invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Colour is the right way to spell it though ;)  I agree with all of this otherwise though. I try to keep edits down to formatting and clarification. I don't like to correct grammar or spelling (unless it's hampering clarity) as we do have a lot of users for whom English is a second language, and hats off to them, because I could never begin to ask these kinds of questions in another language!

Answer (score 5):

The uncontroversial cases would be to edit in order to:

- Fix obvious typos, grammar, punctuation and capitalisation mistakes.
- Apply formatting markup for readability.
- Incorporate clarifications from comments into the post.
- Incorporate references to external resources into the body of the post as quotes or embedded images, when reasonable.
- Replace dead links with archived copies or alternative sources.
- Replace tags with more appropriate ones.

Somewhat more controversially, I think anything that preserves the core intent of the post and doesn’t put words into someone else’s mouth is fair game.  It’s generally not appropriate to change a post that makes claim P to instead say ¬P, or Q; but how it does so, and whether it should say anything about P at all is another matter.  On this and other Stack Exchange sites, I somewhat regularly make edits to:

- Rearrange the flow of text for clarity.
- *Remove* excessive formatting markup for readability.
- Fix tangential problems and misconceptions in the question that aren’t relevant to the core problem posed (e.g. fix a code injection bug in a question that isn’t about injection bugs).
- Replace ASCII punctuation with typographically-correct Unicode punctuation.
- Rewrite ambiguous ‘KB’ or ‘kb’ units into either KiB or kB ([example where I used both](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/21721/2)).
- Rewrite ‘clickbait’ question titles that don’t unambiguously summarise the problem into ones that do ([example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/257121/3) from another site on the network).
- Remove, trim or tone down inflammatory language and lengthy tangents that don’t fit our Q&A format (that might have qualified the post for outright deletion, were they the only content; [example](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/16263/2)).
- Remove ‘interpersonal fluff’ like salutations, [as is standard practice on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) (however, here is an [example](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/16511/2) where I left in ‘Thanks for any advice’, as I took it to mean even partial solutions are welcome).

I have occasionally seen some opposition to such edits, but I generally consider them justified.  The point is that ideally a Q&A pair should solve not only the original asker’s problem, but also be useful to later visitors.  Anything that makes posts more readable, relevant and easier to find for later readers is a net positive, and each post should also serve as example of how posts should be generally written.  Preserving posters’ words exactly is subservient to those goals.

For Community Wiki and tag wiki posts, you probably don’t even need to worry as much about putting words into someone’s mouth, as they belong to the whole community and not to anyone in particular.

Comment: It's just how the units are... kB = kilobyte and KiB is kibibyte. That latter being the horrible word we're forced to use because of marketing departments apparently.

Comment: It can help to edit the title to clarify what the actual question is.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to be the first to comment that hasn't actually edited "that question" :-)

The brouhaha appears to be mainly about whether it is right to remove what for want of a better word I'll call "attitude" from the original post.

I cannot answer the broad scope of the question posed to Meta, but I can say that in this particular instance, I find that the first edits made in that respect (rev 2) were a good-faith attempt to turn a borderline rant into a reasonably-worded question.

It should be noted that the original poster, because of account deletion for some offence or other, is no longer around to either de-rant his own question, or to argue with the edits made to his post. Thus I find arguments about preserving the original voice to be unconvincing.

Comment: On another site I mod I did have to edit a questions recently where OP was clearly angry and the title ended "annoying AF". Made me laugh, and I'd have left it if it didn't have the potential to turn new users away.

Answer (score 1):

*What is this community’s stance on the extent to which editing posts is appropriate?*

You won't get the community's view on the question. Just that of the few users that visit meta and then the subset of them that want to post.

Answering the main question: avoid editing posts. Edit as little as possible.

I edit posts quite a lot. I do so to correct typos' that the poster did not intend, to correct spelling/grammar that makes the post truly incomprehensible or to split up solid blocks of text. It's to improve the accessibility of what the poster has written.

The site is not Wikipedia, where editors strive to improve a group effort that intends to be a definitive text. Individuals express themselves. Others should not come along and interfere with that self-expression or make it someone else's expression in the original poster's name.

I have seen a fairly large number of writers in my time. There are those who think they are great at presentation when they are average, poor or appalling. That is, their styles fail to convey their words' meaning with clarity and their desired expression. There are some on sites that I think are shocking. I would not dream of editing their wording and phrasing, as I find them, to what I would call a better style, though I would find the work easy to do. That would express me, not them.

On some sites, I have seen large changes to posts that took away much of the poster's meaning. I have often noticed this done by Frequent And Worthy members to lesser-known ones, simply because the former can get away with it. They don't try it with higher-reputed members. Every single member has the same standing, regardless of size of contributions. FAW members who migrate to thinking that they own the site in some way can be the biggest causes of a site's unpleasant 'atmosphere', becoming 'gatekeepers'. It's something to stay well away from. The site belongs to everyone and no-one.

All of this take place within the site's remit and guidelines. The site is intended as a reference, with useful questions that users can learn from. However, it is not improved by being unified and discoloured by any few. Editing, like any reinterpretation or censoring, should be done in direct response to a commonly-agreed necessity or standard, not personal taste. I doubt you'll get that defined here, nor should what's here be taken as a definition. And is the idea here is discover the site's opinion and learn from it, changing future behaviour, or merely to affirm existing views. The former is impossible as the sample group will always be tiny and uneven.

Comment: “The site is not Wikipedia, where editors strive to improve a group effort that intends to be a definitive text.” You used to be able to enter the Konami code on the [tour] to get [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ntez.png).

Comment: @wizzwizz4, "You used to be able to" ...and they got rid of it. Maybe it got misused. To post such a thing, it appears that you don't understand my statement and that diagram, though.

Comment: On Stack Exchange sites, we are _absolutely_ trying to create a corpus of definitive knowledge. That's why there's an edit button in the first place. (And we do have standards for how you're supposed to edit; changing formatting from double quotes to single quotes is probably a _bad_ edit, but cutting tangents out of a question is probably a _good_ one, as per Stack Exchange Network guidelines.)

Comment: I do agree with the second half of that paragraph, though. All edits to somebody else's post should be clear, justifiable improvements to the post's function (i.e. making questions better questions, and answers better answers) and should never misrepresent the author's meaning.